# isMinifyEnabled() is deprecated. What is the alternative?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, android-gradle-3.0

I use the below code to automatically generate pro guard mapping file apparently according to product flavors.

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                if (variant.getBuildType().isMinifyEnabled()) {
                    variant.assemble.doLast {
                        copy {
                            from variant.mappingFile
                            into "${rootDir}/proguardTools"
                            rename { String fileName ->
                                "mapping-${variant.name}.txt"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

After upgrading android studio to 3.0 it shows a warning saying `isMinifyEnabled()` is Deprecated and I could not find any solution or an alternative for this `isMinifyEnabled()`. Any help thanks in advance?

[image]

Comment: on android official site it is no where written that it is deprecated

Comment: it is not deprecated

Comment: Then why is the warning?

Comment: may be it is deprecated in if cases but if you set like minifyEnabled=true then it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_3.0.0/build-system/builder-model/src/main/java/com/android/builder/model/BuildType.java#85) of Android Gradle Plugin 3.0:

```
    /**
     * Returns whether minification is enabled for this build type.
     *
     * @return true if minification is enabled.
     * @deprecated remember that this flag means that some "ProGuard-like" tool has run, it does not
     *     say if the tool was used to obfuscate and/or minify. In build system code this
     *     information is available elsewhere and should be used instead of this method.
     */
    @Deprecated
    boolean isMinifyEnabled();
```

This documentation is vague and does not directly tell what to use instead.
In the [blame](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/e6ce692b81e9b1f8bcba7cc4d715a6da1d5d102a%5E%21/build-system/builder-model/src/main/java/com/android/builder/model/BuildType.java) we can see, that it's [Michał Bendowski](http://Micha%C5%82%20Bendowski) that has performed those changes, from whom I have asked to help out with that [question in twitter](https://twitter.com/_azizbekian/status/930145745277280257). Here's the reply:

[image]

Also I cannot see `@Deprecated` annotation in the [latest commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/android-8.0.0_r34/build-system/builder-model/src/main/java/com/android/builder/model/BuildType.java#102) (at the time of writing this it's `android-8.0.0_r34`), which means, that the API is **not** deprecated there.

As a fix, you can suppress that warning putting this line before `if` statement:

```
    //noinspection GrDeprecatedAPIUsage
    if (variant.getBuildType().isMinifyEnabled()) {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to replace `variant.getBuildType().isMinifyEnabled()` with `variant.mappingFile.exists()`.

Where I previously had:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.getBuildType().isMinifyEnabled()) {
        variant.assemble.doLast {
            (new File(variant.mappingFile.parent, "$archivesBaseName-$variant.baseName-mapping.txt")).delete()
            variant.mappingFile.renameTo(variant.mappingFile.parent +
                    "/$archivesBaseName-$variant.baseName-mapping.txt")
        }
    }
}
```

I replaced it with:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.assemble.doLast {
        if (variant.mappingFile != null && variant.mappingFile.exists()) {
            def mappingFilename = "$archivesBaseName-$variant.baseName-mapping.txt"
            (new File(variant.mappingFile.parent, mappingFilename)).delete()
            variant.mappingFile.renameTo(variant.mappingFile.parent +
                    "/" + mappingFilename)
        }
    }
}
```

Or in your case replace

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.getBuildType().isMinifyEnabled()) {
        variant.assemble.doLast {
            copy {
                from variant.mappingFile
                into "${rootDir}/proguardTools"
                rename { String fileName ->
                    "mapping-${variant.name}.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.assemble.doLast {
        if (variant.mappingFile != null && variant.mappingFile.exists()) {
            copy {
                from variant.mappingFile
                into "${rootDir}/proguardTools"
                rename { String fileName ->
                    "mapping-${variant.name}.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how I rearranged the conditions in your code so that the mapping file is searched for only after all other assembly tasks have completed.